# Can't find variable: FileReader

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using drag drop  file functionality in my Project It work fine for all browser. When I drop external file in the safari browser It does not work.

It show me error:

> Can't find variable: FileReader

I am using default function of filereader:-

```
$.each(dataTransfer.files, function (i, file) {
        //debugger;
        var reader = new FileReader();
    }
```

But file File Reader function is not working in the safari. There is any solution for this problem ?.

Comment: What version of Safari? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), Safari's had support for FileReader (outside web workers) since v6. It *doesn't* support FileReader *in* web workers.

Comment: Who is supporting Safari 5 these days?